# Graphics in wine are behind by one update

Tags: wine

As the title says, graphics objects (in particular 3D graphics, but not exclusively) are displaying one update behind.  I first noticed the problem when using google sketchup together with sketchy physics, but this problem actually occurs in all my wine programs.

Specifically, whenever I would click or select or whatever some part of my model in sketchup, the object would not highlight until I did something else that would update the display.  For instance, I click on one of the edges of a cube.  No change to the display.  Then I click on the side of the cube.  The display now shows the edge highlighted.  I tap the delete key, the 3d view now shows the cube with the side highlighted.  I rotate the view, it then shows the cube with one face gone.

While most noticeable while using sketchup, I have occasionally had that problem for a short time while using other programs, however it went away after a while.

What do I need to do to stop this happening?

Information about my environment:

```
Ubuntu 12.10 
Wine 1.4.1
Sketchup 8
Sketchy Physics 3.2

Memory: 7.3 GiB
Processor: AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA 
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 976.6 GB
```

Comment: I've added a question to the end of your, well, question, for clarity.

Comment: Wine 1.4.1 is pretty old now, did you see this problem with newer versions of Wine?

Comment: Could be the graphics or compiz, maybe it doesn't like your graphics card?

Comment: @Braiam No, I've stayed sober since then.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `export vblank_mode=0` before runing `wine sketchup`